# How to convert object into HTML bullet list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an object I retrieve via a JSON AJAX request, which looks like this:

```
{
    "success":false,
    "errors": {
        "name":"Name you entered is not valid!",
        "emailError":"The email address you entered is not valid"
    } 
}
```

Now I need to convert the `errors` property in to an HTML list. This is how I use these errors at this stage:

```
if (!data.success) { // If fails
    if (data.errors.emailError) { 
        $('#messages').fadeIn(1000).append('<div class="response-output">' + data.errors.emailError + '</div>');
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
My server side code look like this:

```
$errors = array(); //To store errors
$form_data = array(); //Pass back the data to `form.php`

if(isset($_POST['your_name'], $_POST['your_email'], $_POST['your_message'])) {

    // Sanitize and validate the data passed in     
    if (preg_match ('/^[A-Z \'.-]{2,60}$/i', $_POST['your_name'])) {
        $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'your_name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    } else {
        $errors['name'] = 'Name you entered is not valid!';
    }

    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'your_email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);  
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Not a valid email
        $errors['emailError'] = 'The email address you entered is not valid';
    }

    // if form fields ok 
    if (empty($errors)) { 
            // --- my mail 

            $mail_sent = mail($sendTo, $subject , $emailbody, implode("\r\n", $headers));

            if ($mail_sent == true){ 
                // Success massege
                $form_data['success'] = true;
                $form_data['posted'] = 'Your requirement have been sent. We will get back to you soon.';    
            }   

    } else {
        $form_data['success'] = false;
    $form_data['errors']  = $errors;
    }

    //Return the data back to form.php
    echo json_encode($form_data);
}
```

But I want to create HTML list inside my `#messages` div. Hope somebody may help me out.

Comment: It would be much easier to do this if you can change the response so that `errors` becomes an array instead of an object. Is that possible?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Can you tell me how can I change the response of this?

Comment: Not really, as you haven't shown us where the response is coming from.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Meantime I updated my question with PHP code

Comment: Can anybody tell why I am getting downvotes for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to iterate over the properties of the `errors` object when `success` is false, and from there create the needed `ul` and `li` elements:

```
if (!json.success) {
    var $ul = $('<ul />').appendTo('#messages');
    for (var key in json.errors) {
        $('<li />', {
            text: key + ': ' + json.errors[key]
        }).appendTo($ul);
    }
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sjzhbrbw/)

Note that the response could be improved by making the `errors` property contain an array instead of an object. How you achieve that would be down to the way you generate the response from the AJAX request.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you tell my how I create an array for these `errors` instead of using an object?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know enough about PHP to help with that. I would suggest starting a different question tagged with PHP.

Comment: Rory, I changed the response to an array. its look lik this - `Array
(
    [name] => Name you entered is not valid!
    [emailError] => The email address you entered is not valid
)`

Comment: Can you tell me how to append above `ul` inside `'<div class="response-output">'` which is insides `#messages`? Thank you.

Comment: Just change the selector in the `.appendTo()` line

Comment: Yes its ok. But I need to create that div dynamically along with `ul`. `ul` should be inside that generated div.